# How to make Unity 2D mouse aiming with constraints?

Tags: c#, mouse, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a script for allowing my player to move his arm with the mouse position.

I want it to have some constraints such as the arms limited to moving a certain distance up and down. Also when the player flips, the arms also flip and allows you to do the same while facing left. How can I do this?

Comment: I would suggest adding a small code snippet or some attempt towards the solution. Most SO users will not write an entire script for you, but will help you with pre-existing code.

Comment: Ok i will add a snippet of the script

Comment: @the-realtom i don't know how to go about writing this though